# Trouble getting local JSON data with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios, response

I'm trying to get data from a local json file using axios. Under the console I can't even get a response so I figured I'd ask about it here.

#### .js file:

```
var loadData;

function loadData() {
    axios({
        url: "[filepath]/json/docs.json", 
        responseType: 'json',
        credentials: "include",
        mode: "no-cors",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }           
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);      
    })
}
```

On the `.then((response)` line it's telling me I have a syntax error---I think it's pertaining to the response syntax but I'm not so sure. Any thoughts?

Comment: Axios cannot read from the file system. It can only make HTTP calls. If you are running in a node environment, look into the `fs` package, this will let you read from the local file system. Otherwise you will need to expose the json file via a webserver to make it accessible to Axios.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use a configuration known to `fetch` in `axios`. Axios doesn't have a lot of those config params

Answer (score 26):

Simply put your json file in public folder and call it using axios.
Suppose if you have json file named called data.json in public folder of your project.

Then call it like

```
    axios.get('data.json')
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Before that make sure to import axios.
like ,

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Too short of an edit, but missing a closing parenthesis on the `.catch()` block.

Comment: Right @C.Helling Thanks for pointing it out. 
I have corrected it.

Answer (score 7):

May I know why you need axios for it? You can directly import the json and use it. The function is not even needed actually. If you still want to retain the function, here's a way.

```
import data from '[filepath]/json/docs.json'

function loadData() {
  return data;
}
```

Comment: The original data is XML and came from a url. Since the data I'm using now is for testing purposes it's in JSON and is a local file.

Comment: the data is out of the src folder. React restrict import out of the src folder.

Answer (score 6):

Use fetch

```
test() {
    fetch('[filepath]/json/docs.json')
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(json => {
      })
}
```

Or put your file in the public folder

```
axios.get('docs.json') .then(//...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use file system than axios in this case.

Get the package

```
npm i fs
```

Import it

```
import fs from "fs";
```

Read file

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile("path/file.json", "utf8", (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        }
        res.render("index.ejs", {
            data : JSON.parse(data)
        });
    });
});
```

Make sure to catch the results in loop. I use EJS, so here is the code

```
<% data.forEach(titles => { %>
    <h1><%= titles.title %></h1>
<% }); %>
```