# Why does JavaScript render data from the useEffect() hook but fails to render the data when put in the function body?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have a JSON file called `teams.json` that contains the basic structure ("name", "age", "country", "role", "team", and "image") in an object. I'm using React to use the function `fetch()` to retrieve the data from the **local** JSON file. When I call the useEffect (shown below) hook, the data is retrieved from the local JSON file and I'm able call a `useState` function to store the data in a state variable called `data`.

**useEffect() function call**

```js
//file path
filePath = "/src/public/teams.json"
const getData = (file) => {
   fetch(file)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data => setData(data))
   .catch(err => console.log("Error fetching data", err)
}
  
useEffect(() => {
   getData(filePath)
}, [filePath])
```

If I try to edit or access data within the useEffect() hook, the data is able to be retrieved without any problems, as such.

```js
.then(data => console.log(data[0]))
```

This returns a json object that contains the necessary information.

```json
{
  "name":"R",
  "image":"https://example.com",
  "team":"B",
  "role":"WB",
  "country":"American",
  "age":18
}
```

However, in the main body of my react App, if I try to obtain data from the data state, it gives me an error saying `Cannot read properties of undefined`, shown below.

**Body of React App**

```js
return (
   <main>
      {data[0].country}
    </main>
  )
```

But I get this error:

[image: Error Screenshot]

I've tried solutions to previous forums from:

[Stack Overflow Discussion Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224164/trouble-getting-local-json-data-with-axios)

[Stack Overflow Discussion Error Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569968/unable-to-fetch-data-from-local-json-file-by-axios)

I've moved my project to the structure:

```
-src
--public
*some files*
```

and put the JSON file in the public folder. It reads it now but still doesn't render. I've also tried using axios but to no avail.

If this is an easy fix, sorry about that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the state before the async request completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data isn't loaded yet.

Assuming your app is something like

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState();
  const getData = (file) => {
    fetch(file)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data))
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error fetching data", err));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(filePath);
  }, [filePath]);

  return <main>{data[0].country}</main>;
}
```

you're starting off with an `undefined` data.

Add a guard against that:

```
if(!data) return <>Loading...</>;
return <main>{data[0].country}</main>;
```

Comment: Also is there any way I can render the data first then put it in the body?

Comment: There is no data to render if it hasn't been loaded...